# Should I use Sharepoint Number column types to store monetary values?

Tags: sharepoint, currency

In SharePoint I can create a list column of type 'Number'. I need to store monetary amounts and would like to be able to use this column type rather than having to create a new one.

Are values of this type stored and manipulated by SharePoint (e.g. when summing values in a list view) to prevent loss of precision (i.e. not as some kind of approximate floating point type)?

I have looked at currency columns but they seem to force display of a currency unit which doesn't make sense in my application (and I have a suspicion that they are stored as 'Numbers' under the bonnet).

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a currency field?

Comment: I don't want to display the currency unit. Can I do this with a currency field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although not conclusive, based on the following tests it looks like SharePoint handles numbers in a way suitable for monetary calculations (at least with WSS 3.0/SQL Server 2005) even though they are stored approximately. However, **values with over 15 significant figures can exhibit rounding errors**:

**Test for money storage and retrieval**

Three number columns (`First`, `Second` and `Third`) containing 3.7, 3.65 and 0.05 respectively (.Net example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money/316731#316731)) and a calculated column (returning a single line of text) with the following formula: `=IF(First=Second+Third,"Success","Failure")`. On viewing the list the calculated column displays **Success**.

**Test for money calculations**

A Yes/No calculated column with the formula `=0.1+0.1+0.1=0.3` (.Net example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money/316737#316737)). On viewing the list the calculated column displays **Yes**.

**Test for money storage and calculation I**

In a list called `TestList`, a custom number column (`CustomNumber`) contains 304253.3251 (SQL Server example from [Microsoft White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bae8beec-9892-4ecd-a9db-292254895f9c&displaylang=en)). This is stored in database table `AllUserData`, column `float1` of type `float` (SQL Server 2005). `float` is an approximate data type.

Running the following queries:

```
DECLARE @ListName UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @ListName = (SELECT tp_Id FROM AllLists WHERE tp_Title = 'TestList')

SELECT CAST(float1 as NUMERIC(18, 11)) AS CustomNumber 
FROM AllUserData 
WHERE tp_ListId = @ListName

SELECT float1 AS CustomNumber
FROM AllUserData 
WHERE tp_ListId = @ListName
```

Gives the following results:

```
CustomNumber
304253.32510000002

CustomNumber
304253.3251
```

Creating a calculated column with the formula `=CustomNumber*100000000000` which might be expected to display the incorrect value of `30425332510000002` actually **displays the correct (from the user's perspective) value of `30,425,332,510,000,000.00000`**. I assume that this behaviour is due to the code reading the `float` value from the database doing a cast to `numeric` with a suitably small number of decimal places and manipulating the values in memory using the .Net Decimal type.

There are [suggestions](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic544518-9-2.aspx), however, that on SQL Server 2000 calculation errors may manifest in this case since the behaviour of `float` values has been altered between the versions.

**Test for money storage and retrieval II**

Based on the results from the previous test add the following value to the `CustomNumber` column: 9999999999999999.

This 16 significant digit value is **displayed incorrectly in the list (and edit) views as 10,000,000,000,000,000** (using a value with 15 digits displays correctly).

Inspecting the `AllUserData` table shows that the value is stored incorrectly in the database and running the following query:

```
DECLARE @f FLOAT
SET @f = 9999999999999999
SELECT CAST(@f as NUMERIC(20, 0))
```

Gives the result:

```
10000000000000000
```

Which demonstrates that SQL Server is rounding the number on insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Number is intended to be used that way, yes.  You shouldn't have any trouble with a loss of precision when summing values.

Comment: Do you have a reference (MSDN?) confirming this?

Comment: Boy, you're going to make me work for that accept, aren't you!  No, I can't find any documentation stating that.  I believe Currency and Number are both stored in SQL Server as doubles.  With the range of values used for money, you won't run into any precision issues when backed by a double.

Comment: Using double for money is generally a bad idea, though (see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money)...