# How do I format cents and dollars in C#? How do I convert one to the other?

Tags: c#, decimal, currency

If I have something written as 25 cents in either C# or Java, how would I convert that to read $.25?

Answer (score 9):

You should probably use the `Decimal` datatype, and then instead of trying to convert cents to dollars, use one standard notation:

```
Decimal amount = .25M;
String.Format("Amount: {0:C}", amount);
```

The output is: `Amount: $0.25`;

Comment: The important reason to use Decimal for money: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money

Comment: @TheBigO yup, I actually linked to that in a now deleted answer given below by another user.

Comment: Actually, I would argue against Decimal for money (and rather a specific monetary type including "all the details support"), but it's a good bit better than using a float -- it still is relative precision and can, in degenerate cases or extremes, exhibit the same "problems" as using a float.

Comment: @pst Microsoft seems to think it's suitable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: A *very* contrived case: `decimal m = Decimal.MaxValue - 1; (m / 3m * 3m) == m; // false` (although I suppose this is akin to saying that GUIDs will "run out" soon). Also the rules for dealing the money can be rather complex (who gets the change in a split?) and there may be a *smallest monetary unit*. Of course this post/question is well below those scopes.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Money
{
    public int Dollar {get; set;}
    public int Cent { get; set;}

    public Money(int cents)
    {
        this.Dollar = Math.Floor(cents/100);
        this.Cent = cents%100;
    }
}
```

and u can use it like so

```
int cents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline("Please enter cents to convert:"))
Money money = new Money(cents);
Console.Writeline("$" + money.Dollar + "." + money.Cent);
```

Comment: Should we use  array for it ?

Comment: well, depends on how many of these you need. you can create a List<Money> money = new List<Money>(); to store alot of these

Comment: console.readline( frome user),  console.writeline( you have X cent ,or x Dollar and x cent)

Comment: are you asking how to incorporate console.readline and writeline into it? or stating that you can do it? or asking if you need an array for readline and writeline? what's your final goal? to parse a list of cents or to get cents from a user one at a time and print it out straight away?

Comment: Please edit your inital question to ask exactly what you need. include as much info as possible so we can help you.

Comment: @Joe ,thanks  dear I mean I want a program , when user  give its cent its convert to Dollars . example : 100 cent = 1 $ dollar or another example 125 cent = 1 $ dollar and 25 cent ?

Comment: ok, so i've included the readline, user enters the amount, then it's converted and printed out, and you have the money object just in case you want to store it. still don't know what you want with an array... you don't need an array for this.

Comment: no worries, glad to help :) although next time, just say, i want a full program that will take in cents and output dollars and cents.

Comment: Oh dear so thsnks .but I try to write this code with arry but I got a lot probelm . thanks  again for your time and attention . Sir have a good night ,thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting seems wrong for cents < 10, i.e. "$1.1"?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is **Best Answer** I write  with Array

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Please input your cent or dollar");

        int coins = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] dollars = new int[2];

         dollars[0] = coins / 100;
         dollars[1] = coins % 100;



        Console.WriteLine("{0} dollar and {1} coins", dollars[0], dollars[1]);
        Console.ReadLine();






    }
```