# What data type to use for some number, date and phone number in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle

Hi I have an application in asp.net which contains four text fields for number, amount, date and telephone. When clicked on a button these values has to be saved into Oracle Database. Used procedures to save these values. In oracle database datatypes are, number column is of type number, amount column is of type number, date column is of type datetime and phonenumber is of type number. I am using validations for all four text fields so that these values are in proper format. In my code I am passing number, date, telephone as string and amount as double. Is this the best pratice ? If not can any one suggest me the data types I have to use for 4 fields (number, amount, date and telephone number) ?

Comment: well I would say phone number should be a string in case you want to save it in the format: +49 005 544 5454 or whatever else with leading zeros...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works, it's "good enough" practice. You're not doing this a million times in a loop, so efficiency isn't an issue. What you are doing is clear and understandable and is a good fit for the types of data that you're handling. Date and phone number formats are tricky in editing. Do you have to deal with international dates (much of the world is fond of dd-mm-yy) and non-US  phone numbers? I like your data types.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should use `decimal` in C# to represent `number` fields in a database; use `DateTime` in C# to represent `datetime` fields in a DB.

I do not recommend using a `number` field to store things that only contain digits but aren't actual numbers (like credit card numbers, phone numbers, ZIP codes, and SSNs). A string (`varchar`) better represents those values.

Comment: oracle doesn't have a datetime datatype, the date datatype holds both date and time however.

Comment: @Jamiegs: The OP states "date column is of type datetime" so I just repeated what they said.

Answer (score 0):

Store the amount (assuming this is monetary) as a number(14,2) or something similar.  Don't use a double, as some decimals can't be expressed precisely as a double.  In C# use the decimal type, and in Oracle a number type.

See also:
[Is a double really unsuitable for money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money)