# How to fix error in money representation by Double?

Tags: c#, .net, double, decimal, currency

I'm using the type double to represent monetary values.
As you know some number are not represented correctly, like 19,7949999999.... Is approximated to 19,80.

How can I resolve this?
I tried to use Decimal instead but I still have the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have the same problem with decimal. What kind of calculations are you doing? (And maybe I'm misunderstanding: you say 19.794999 is approximated to 19.80 - you want the nines-recurring value? There's no way double would get rounded between 19.795 and 19.80 - they're too far apart, double has enough precision to distinguish those.)

Comment: Decimal is the best for monetary vals, show the code seems something wrong in how you dealing with it

Comment: Can you show some code using `decimal` that still shows these problems? The amount of space set aside for the mantissa in `decimal` is pretty incredible.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money for more info

Comment: Now that we have the answers, Can we have the question !

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, use need to use `System.Decimal`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), which is built to represent base 10 numbers accurately.

If you already tried using `Decimal`, make sure you never still use double, as that could be causing the error to not go away. If you only use `Decimal`, you shouldn't have any issues.