# How to save prices in a variable from List Box items

Tags: c#

I have a listbox with prices now I need to make a label to show the total off all the prices in that listbox. Now I need to make a variable to save every price that is entered in the listbox so then i show the total in the label.

Comment: Well... just loop through the listbox's Items, but wouldn't it be easier to just sum it before binding the values to the listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all Items in `ListBox` and sum it up.

Try This:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (var v in listBox1.Items)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDecimal(v);
        }
        label1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: [Don't use a `double` to store money, use `decimal`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money)

Comment: the code is good but when for example make 80 and 80 in the listbox the label shows 240 as a total and not 160

Comment: @user3328666: no dear it works fine, are you clearing the ListBox items before adding new items using `ListBox1.Items.Clear()`

Comment: I made the items.clear after this code "label1.Text = total.ToString();" and the total is good but now the prices are not showing in the list box

Comment: @user3328666: no no , you should not clear the items everytime, what i meant was you need to clear your listbox items before adding new items , if you are only adding items once then you should not remove it, please share the code, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ`

```
var total = listBox1.Items.OfType<object>()
            .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x.ToString())).Sum();
var label1.Text = total.ToString();
```