# C# Calculate total price with datetime and price with live update in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a wpf application in C# which is used to book houses.
I want to calculate the total price of a reservation. I have 2 datetimes: Check in & Check Out.
The calculation I need to use = `(CheckOut - CheckIn).TotalDays * BnB.Price`
BnB.Price is the price per night.

I want the totalprice to update live in the guest View.

[image: Image of where totalprice is]

So whenever I change the check in and out dates the total price automatically changes.

This is my Reservation Model:

```
    private double _totalprice { get; set; }
    private DateTime _checkIn { get; set; }
    private DateTime _checkOut { get; set; }

    public double TotalPrice
    { get => _totalprice; set { _totalprice = value; Notify("TotalPrice"); } }

    public DateTime CheckIn
    { get => _checkIn; set { if (value < _checkOut) { _checkIn = value; }; Notify("CheckIn"); } }

    public DateTime CheckOut
    { get => _checkOut; set { if (value > _checkIn) { _checkOut = value; }; Notify("CheckOut"); } }
```

If I missed something please let me know!

Comment: What is `BnB`? Is that a member of the Reservation Model as well?

Comment: BnB is the model for the house

Comment: Is it a member of the Reservation Model? Does the Reservation Model have a reference to `BnB`?

Comment: Yes, Yes it does  `private BnB? _bnb { get; set; }
        public BnB? BnB
        { get => _bnb; set { _bnb = value; Notify("BnB"); } }` This code is in the reservation model

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in your question, `BnB` is a member of the reservation model. Given that, you can change `TotalPrice` to a readonly property, a property without a `set` method, and just caluclate the total in the `get` method. Then, in the setters for `CheckIn` and `CheckOut`, call `Notify("TotalPrice")` to update the UI. You also need to call `Notify("TotalPrice")` in the setter for `BnB`, since that member participates in the calculation of `TotalPrice`.

This assumes that the Reservation Model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and that `Notify` invokes the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public class Reservation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BnB? _bnb;
    private DateTime _checkIn;
    private DateTime _checkOut;
    
    public double TotalPrice
    {
        // Instead of using a field, just calculate TotalPrice on the fly.
        get 
        {
            // Check for nulls - since _bnb is the only thing that is
            // is nullable in the calculation, it is the only thing we
            // need to check.
            if (BnB== null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return (CheckOut - CheckIn).TotalDays * BnB.Price;
        }
    }

    public BnB BnB
    {
        get => _bnb;
        set
        {
            if (_bnb != value)
            {
                _bnb = value;
                Notify(nameof(BnB));
                Notify(nameof(TotalPrice));
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime CheckIn
    {
        get => _checkIn;
        set
        {
            if (value != _checkIn && value < _checkOut)
            {
                // I've changed the check to ensure that the new value isn't the
                // same as the current value. No sense running this code if nothing
                // has actually changed.
                _checkIn = value;                
            }

            // Without knowing what Notify does exactly, I can't say for sure. But
            // if it is only invoking the PropertyChanged event then these two lines
            // should probably be placed inside the if statement. There isn't any
            // point to notifying the UI that a change happened if a change didn't
            // actually happen.
            Notify(nameof(CheckIn));

            // You can notify the UI to update TotalPrice within a setter for a
            // different property.
            Notify(nameof(TotalPrice));
        }
    }

    public DateTime CheckOut
    {
        get => _checkOut;
        set
        {
            if (value != _checkOut&& value > _checkIn)
            {
                _checkOut = value;                
            }

            // These might make more sense inside the if statement as well.
            Notify(nameof(CheckOut));
            Notify(nameof(TotalPrice));
        }
    }

    // Other members of the Reservation model.
}
```

If you really need to have `TotalPrice` be a property with a getter / setter and a backing field, then just set the `TotalPrice` property when you set `CheckIn`, `CheckOut`, or `BnB`.

```
public class Reservation
{
    private BnB? _bnb;
    private DateTime _checkIn;
    private DateTime _checkOut;
    private double _totalPrice;

    public double TotalPrice
    {
        get => _totalPrice;
        set
        {
            if (_totalPrice != value)
            {
                _totalPrice = value;
                Notify("TotalPrice");
            }
        }
    }

    public BnB BnB
    {
        get => _bnb;
        set
        {
            if (_bnb != value)
            {
                _bnb = value;
                Notify(nameof(BnB));
                TotalPrice = CalculateTotalPrice();
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime CheckIn
    {
        get => _checkIn;
        set
        {
            if (value != _checkIn && value < _checkOut)
            {
                // I've changed the check to ensure that the new value isn't the
                // same as the current value. No sense running this code if nothing
                // has actually changed.
                _checkIn = value;                
            }

            // Without knowing what Notify does exactly, I can't say for sure. But
            // if it is only invoking the PropertyChanged event then these two lines
            // should probably be placed inside the if statement. There isn't any
            // point to notifying the UI that a change happened if a change didn't
            // actually happen.
            Notify(nameof(CheckIn));

            // You can notify the UI to update TotalPrice within a setter for a
            // different property.
            TotalPrice = CalculateTotalPrice();
        }
    }

    public DateTime CheckOut
    {
        get => _checkOut;
        set
        {
            if (value != _checkOut&& value > _checkIn)
            {
                _checkOut = value;                
            }

            // These might make more sense inside the if statement as well.
            Notify(nameof(CheckOut));
            TotalPrice = CalculateTotalPrice();
        }
    }

    private double CalculateTotalPrice()
    {
        if (BnB== null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return (CheckOut - CheckIn).TotalDays * BnB.Price;
    }

    // Other members of the Reservation model.   
}
```

Also, on a side note you might want to consider switching from [`double` to `decimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316727/is-a-double-really-unsuitable-for-money) to represent currency.

Comment: You have to check for `null` in the `TotalPrice` getter and return an appropriate value, such as `0`, if any of the members participating in the calculation are `null`. I've updated the answer to account for this, and added an example of what to do if you really want a property with a get/set and a backing field for `TotalPrice`.

Comment: I made the column table nullable so it kinda works now. the problem I now have is the incorrect date. it shows a date of 1-1-0001 instead of todays date. whenever adding a new reservation the default date is todays date. CheckOut = DateTime.Today. Here is a link to an image showing the problem: https://ibb.co/nD8p1gG

Comment: It looks like you're setting `CheckOut = DateTime.Today` but `CheckIn` to `default(DateTime)` or `DateTime.MinValue`, but I don't know because I can't see the code where you're setting them. You need to set `CheckIn` to an appropriate value when you create a new reservation.